# how to create a temporary table in mysql using spring jdbctemplate

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I am using the springmvc for getting the request from client and spring jdbc template to connect the mysql database.

```
String query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (temp_id int, temp_type varchar(100) 
NOT NULL, temp_date date NOT NULL, temp_description varchar(2048) NOT NULL)";

this.jdbcTemplate.update(query);
```

After successful execution i am not getting any exception. but table is not created.

Comment: I am using spring mvc and spring jdbc template and mysql

Comment: Please edit your question in order to add information instead of putting it into comments.

Comment: `create temporary table ...`

Comment: I can able to create temporary table in mysql work bench directly, but I can't able to create table by using jdbc template through application.